# I get "Type mismatch. Required: State<String?> Found: String" when Using viewModel.observeAsState() with Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating an app that takes users input in a textfield and instead of using:

```
var textState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
```

I opted for using viewModels like

```
var title : State<String?> = addTaskViewModel.title.observeAsState()

TextField(
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
value = title.value!!,
onValueChange = { title = it },
shape = textFieldShape,
colors = textFieldColors,
label = {Text("Add a title",)} )
```

I get an error

> Type mismatch. Required: State<String?> Found: String

when setting  `onValueChange = { title = it }` on the TextField widget.

How can I use `viewModel.observeAsState()` with a TextField?

Comment: I *think* this is kotlin, but please update the tag if I misidentified the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create inside the `ViewModel` class a function to change this value.

Something like:

```
class TaskViewModel : ViewModel() {

    //Just an example
    private var _title = MutableLiveData("")
    var title: LiveData<String> = _title

    fun onTitleChange(newName: String) {
        _title.value = newName
    }
}
```

and then:

```
val title : State<String> = taskViewModel.title.observeAsState("")
TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        value = title.value,
        onValueChange = { taskViewModel.onTitleChange(it) },
        label = {Text("Add a title")} )
```

or:

```
  val title: String by taskViewModel.title.observeAsState("")
  TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        value = title,
        onValueChange = { taskViewModel.onTitleChange(it) },
        label = {Text("Add a title")} )
```